# Retrying in X second EOF when pushing Docker Image to Azure Container Registry

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, windows-server-2019

After building a docker image on a Windows 2019 server when I attempt to push the image to Azure Container Registry I keep getting a 'Retrying in xx seconds' until it eventually writes a line that says EOF and stops.

```
6ad7e5ca6b3f: Retrying in 1 second    
349c7f00d08e: Layer already exists    
370f72f4d447: Layer already exists    
8dc6654a61c6: Layer already exists    
8fa655db5360: Layer already exists    
EOF
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

I have a few Windows 2019 servers running docker in experimental mode and they all do the same thing, however if I try to push from my local dev machine (running Windows 10) it works fine.

Here is the base image in my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

If I remove the 2.2-stretch-slim tag it pushes no problem (this works):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

Why do I get the error pushing from Windows Server 2019 using 2.2-stretch-slim but yet it works fine pushing from my Windows 10 machine?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this ?

Comment: No, I left the stretch-slim off my image.

Comment: I had a similar a problem. Somehow the proxy of my company was in the way. Disconnecting from my company VPN, unsetting any "HTTP_PROXY" env-var and disabling proxy from my Docker Desktop (I'm using MacOS) solved the problem.
I still don't understand why, since some layers could successfully be pushed but not the big ones (typically >= 100MB)